# Stopwatch giving different results depending on where code resides

Tags: c#, c++, c#-4.0

I'm getting some confusing `Stopwatch` results in my C# project. Consider the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] myEventArray = GetEventByteArrayFromDatabase();
    byte[] myEventItemsArray = GetEventItemByteArrayFromDatabase();
    uint numEvents = 1000;
    uint numEventItems = 1000;

    Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    TestFunction(ref myEventArray, numEvents, ref myEventItemsArray, numEventItems);
    sw1.Stop();

    float timeTakenInSeconds = (float)sw2.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    Console.WriteLine("Total time: " + timeTakenInSeconds + " seconds. ");
}

static void TestFunction(ref byte[] EventArray, uint numEvents, ref byte[] EventItemArray, uint numEventItems)
{
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        calc.Test(EventArray, numEvents, EventItemArray, numEventItems);
}
```

I run this, and get a time of around 0.2 seconds.
Now consider this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] myEventArray = GetEventByteArrayFromDatabase();
    byte[] myEventItemsArray = GetEventItemByteArrayFromDatabase();
    uint numEvents = 1000;
    uint numEventItems = 1000;

    Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    calc.Test(myEventArray , numEvents, myEventItemsArray , numEventItems);
    sw1.Stop();

    float timeTakenInSeconds = (float)sw1.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    Console.WriteLine("Total time: " + timeTakenInSeconds + " seconds. ");
}
```

I run that, and get a similar result, as one would expect.
Finally, check this out:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] myEventArray = GetEventByteArrayFromDatabase();
    byte[] myEventItemsArray = GetEventItemByteArrayFromDatabase();
    uint numEvents = 1000;
    uint numEventItems = 1000;

    TestFunction(ref myEventArray, numEvents, ref myEventItemsArray, numEventItems);
}

static void TestFunction(ref byte[] EventArray, uint numEvents, ref byte[] EventItemArray, uint numEventItems)
{
    Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    calc.Test(EventArray, numEvents, EventItemArray, numEventItems);
    sw1.Stop();

    float timeTakenInSeconds = (float)sw1.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    Console.WriteLine("Total time: " + timeTakenInSeconds + " seconds. ");
}
```

When I run *that*, the timing result is consistently *ten times faster* for some reason.
Any ideas why that could be the case?

**A bit more info:**
The Calculator class is defined in C++/CLI.  I'm using it as a wrapper for native C++ code that eventually works with the byte arrays.
I'm also compiling with the "unsafe" compiler flag.  Not sure if that could be having any effect.
All code is compiled in release mode.

Comment: Are you running this code in debug or release? Also, it looks like you're timing different methods. `TestFunction` takes a `ref` parameter while `Test` doesn't.

Comment: What happens if you activate both StopWatches? (inside TestFunction() and inside Main())

Comment: check `sw1` vs. `sw2` (you mixed these names in an unfortunate way)

Comment: Sorry the sw1/sw2 thing was a typo.  Fixed it.

Comment: And now test the code posted in your question again after all those changes ;)

Comment: The CLR is very likely to be performing some optimalization here to allow for the CLI transition.

Comment: Can you try calling Calculator.Test before your timing code, so that the method has already been JIT compiled when it is timed?

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered the reason for this.  It happens because in the first case, the creation of my Calculator object was included in the timing result, and in the 3rd case it was not.

If I understand this correctly,
Stack variables are not actually created on the line you type "new()", the compiler moves the memory allocation to the method "prolog".

See this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tawsa7cb.aspx

"The prolog saves argument registers in their home addresses if required, pushes nonvolatile registers on the stack, **allocates the fixed part of the stack for locals and temporaries**, and optionally establishes a frame pointer."

So my "case 1" included the "new" (because it happened in the prolog of TestFunction) and "case 3" excluded it, because the "new" had already happened.

Comment: Interesting. I'd think the actual allocation would be the biggest hit on performance here.

Comment: The actual allocation was the biggest hit - it just wasn't happening where I thought it was.